# Test functionality in the Job Class

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, lumen, laravel-queue

I like to test (Feature test via phpunit) some methods in the Job Class (Lumen Queue) to make sure it is working correctly.

Problem is Job Class have some jobs methods like `$this->job->getJobId()` and `$this->release(5);`

If I run phpunit from console, I get an error:

> Error: Call to a member function getJobId() on null

The test code look like this:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function it_has_successfully_uploaded()
{        
    $job = new SomeJob(['file' => ['file1.zip']]);

    $job->handle();
}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you show the source of your job and the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @sisve Stripped version it look somethin like that https://kopy.io/D9maN - There is no issue using `dispatch()`  but to do testing via phpunit caused problem because I am creating `SomeJob` object so I can test rather than using `dispatch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using `$this->job->getJobId()`, but nowhere is that property declared or set. Are you perhaps using the InteractsWithQueue trait but forgot to include that in your code paste?

If so, the job property is set in [InteractsWithQueue::setJob](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Queue/InteractsWithQueue.php#L70-L75). This method may be called from several places, but in your case it is probably from [Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler::setJobInstanceIfNecessary](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php#L88-L90). This is some internal initialization of your job that Laravel does for you, which you must imitate in your test setup.

I would implement a simplistic version of [Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Job](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Queue/Job.php) and call `$job->setJob(new SimplisticVersionShazaamJob(...));` before calling `$job->handle()`.

Comment: `InteractsWithQueue` is already included in Lumen in the `Job` abstract class. https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/app/Jobs/Job.php

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back So why it was before tagged as Laravel 5.5 and you talked about Laravel?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Mistake on my part. Even `InteractsWithQueue` is already included - it doesn't solve problem. So I am testing @sisve suggestion right now using  `$job->setJob()`